# Makefile Argument string comparision

Tags: bash, makefile

I am passing an argument to makefile target. I want to do string compare of the argument. This is my code,

```
mode = p
install:
    @echo mode is $(mode)
    ifeq ($(mode),"p")
        @echo mode is production
    else
        @echo mode is development
    endif
```

I get the following error as,

```
mode is d
ifeq (d,"p")
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

What is the error and what is General rule for comparing strings in bash scripts?

Comment: Another question - "How are you passing mode to make?" With `make mode=d ...`?

Comment: `make mode=d install`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using pure make syntax (`ifeq`) as a recipe (the line starts with a tab). Try this, instead:

```
mode = p
install:
    @echo mode is $(mode)
ifeq ($(mode),p)
    @echo mode is production
else
    @echo mode is development
endif
```

Comment: I got the error `*** missing separator.  Stop.` in the line `    @echo mode is development`.

Comment: Make recipes start with a tab character. Not spaces. Do not just copy-paste the code. Edit it and replace the leading spaces by one tab character.

Comment: Thank you. This is my input command. `make mode=d install`. My output as follows, 
`mode is d
mode is development
`
but for the input `sudo make mode=p install`, It also runs the else statement. My output is,
`mode is p
mode is development`

Comment: My fault: I copy-pasted your code and only slightly modified it. I should have been more careful: remove the `"` around `"p"`. Make strings are not `"` delimited. So the `"` characters are part of the string and the comparison between `p` and `"p"` fails. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I learned something new from you. Sometimes doing fault may be useful for others to learn not to do. :) It works fine. Thank you.