# How to compare two string variables in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have the following code:

```
LOCAL_VERSION := $(shell some_binary -v | head -n 1)
REMOTE_VERSION := $(shell curl -s https://example.com/key)

all:
    ifeq($(REMOTE_VERSION), $(LOCAL_VERSION))
        @echo yes
    endfi
```

But I am getting this:

```
user:tmp user$ make
ifeq(v0.11.1, v0.11.1)
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `v0.11.1,'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `ifeq(v0.11.1, v0.11.1)'
make: *** [all] Error
```

I am on Mac OSX, but it's using GNU Make anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Makefile Argument string comparision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55096365/makefile-argument-string-comparision)

Comment: @RenaudPacalet thanks!!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`ifeq` should **not be indented,** e.g.

```
LOCAL_VERSION := $(shell some_binary -v | head -n 1)
REMOTE_VERSION := $(shell curl -s https://example.com/key)

all:
ifeq ($(REMOTE_VERSION), $(LOCAL_VERSION))
    @echo yes
else
    @echo NO
endif
```

Comment: Hi Alex. Thank you. That solved the problem. I didn't know it wasn't supposed to be indended.

Comment: The trick with makefile syntax is that when a line after a target begins with a tab character, this lines is not a make statement anymore, but rather is passed (after $ variables and functions are evaluated) to the shell, as a command that is supposed to build the target. `ifeq` is not a valid command for the shell.

Comment: This worked for me, too. Fixed an "unexpected token error".

Comment: I wonder how this is different in `define` macro. Should I use `$$`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not that ifeq is indented in the recipe, the problem is that it was indented using a tab. If you indent using space, the code runs as expected.

From Make manual:
5.1 Recipe Syntax

> Each line in the recipe must start with a tab (or the first character in the value of the .RECIPEPREFIX variable; see Special Variables), except that the first recipe line may be attached to the target-and-prerequisites line with a semicolon in between. Any line in the makefile that begins with a tab and appears in a “rule context” (that is, after a rule has been started until another rule or variable definition) will be considered part of a recipe for that rule. Blank lines and lines of just comments may appear among the recipe lines; they are ignored.