# Makefile: write conditional statement for the shell

Tags: bash, makefile, command-line-arguments

I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47008498/6637004) as a basis for how to pass arguments to a make target.

I would like to perform a string comparison on this command line arg, using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55097298/6637004) as inspiration for doing string equality comparisons in a makefile.

**Update** using the suggested answer below:

```
%:
    @:

test:
    if [ '$(filter-out $@,$(MAKECMDGOALS))' = hi ]; \
        echo "WON"; \
    else \
        echo "LOST"; \
    fi
```

**where I do 8 spaces instead of indents, nothing prints.** When I do tabs instead of spaces, I get the following errors:

```
if [ 'hi' = hi ]; \
        echo "WON"; \
    else \
        echo "LOST"; \
    fi
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `if [ 'hi' = hi ];     echo "WON"; else    echo "LOST"; fi'
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

Original attempt:

```
%:
        @:

test:
        ifeq ($(filter-out $@,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),hi)
                echo "WON"
        else
                echo "LOST"
        endif
```

However, when I run, `make test hi`, I get

```
arg="hi"
ifeq (hi,hi)
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `hi,hi'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `ifeq (hi,hi)'
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

What is the unexpected token ?

Answer (score 3):

`ifeq` is a *make* directive.  By indenting it with a TAB, you have put it into the recipe, and all commands in the recipe are passed to the shell.  The shell has no idea what an `ifeq` command is, and can't understand all the parens here, so you get these errors.

If you want to conditionalize on an automatic variable like `$@`, which are only available in the recipe, you have to write a *shell* conditional statement you can't use a make conditional statement:

```
test:
        if [ '$(filter-out $@,$(MAKECMDGOALS))' = hi ]; then \
            echo "WON"; \
        else \
            echo "LOST"; \
        fi
```

Comment: is there special spacing we need to do? When I run `make test hi`, nothing  prints out

Comment: when I indent the `if/else` statement, I get `if [ 'hi' = hi ]; \
  echo "WON"; \
 else \
  echo "LOST"; \
 fi
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `if [ 'hi' = hi ];  echo "WON"; else  echo "LOST"; fi'
make: *** [test] Error 2`

Comment: Sorry, forgot the _then_

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this answer as the one posted doesn't work as it is missing a `then`

```
test:
        if [ '$(filter-out $@,$(MAKECMDGOALS))' = hi ]; then \
            echo "WON"; \
        else \
            echo "LOST"; \
        fi
```

shell conditionals go `if [] then ... else ... fi`

Comment: Omitting the `then` was a small error that MadScientist has corrected; it would be appropriate to accept his answer.